# Store multi dimensional map in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a game and want to store positions in a 2d map. Those positions are in pixels, so for example:

```
{ _id: 1111, map: [
  { x: 850,  y: 2000 },
  { x: 950,  y: 2000 },
  { x: 1050, y: 2000 }
]}
```

I also thought doing someting like:

```
{ _id: 1111, map: [
  850:  [2000],
  950:  [2000],
  1050: [2000]
]}
```

What's the best data structure for a map like this one? Where `0 < x < 2000` and `0 < y < 2000`

More details:

- When fetching a game, I need the full map, I don't need to query only a subset of the map
- I want the map to be as small as possible to store.
- More than 3000 elements can be in the map.

Comment: Can you provide some information around the queries that you need to be fast. It sounds like you want to be able to quickly retrieve one full map. Will you ever need to retrieve the map conditionally on the position data? Also, are you planning to write out full copies of the map as part of a state saving process, or are you doing this via updating position info through updates/upserts? Thanks

Comment: Interesting question.. In my use-case, I'm only adding new positions in the map. No updates, no removals.

Comment: Ok, so you have a bunch of documents, and you are updating the map with new positions, is that correct? Do you need to enforce each position to be unique? Also, what does one document represent--I like to get an idea of the scale. For instance, does this map represent state for a single user or is it a global share state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you care about is keeping a concise map, I would just store an array of integers where one integer represents a point. You use bitwise math to derive x,y:

eg) 65537 = (bits) 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 = x=z>>16, y=z&0xFFFF = (1,1)

UDPATE: Here is some sample JavaScript as requested:

```
function intToPos(i)
{
    var x= i >> 16;
    var y= i&0xFFFF;

    console.log(x+","+y);
}

var positions=[65537,131074,196611];

for (var i=0; i < positions.length; i++)
{
   intToPos(positions[i])
}
```

UPDATE: posToInt function:

```
function posToInt(x,y)
{
    var pos= (x<<16)|y;

    console.log(pos);

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example in python or php or js ...?

Comment: I've provided a js example above

Comment: Thanks, can you provide posToInt() too?

Comment: Congrats, your solution is awesome! I prefer your's because I don't have to define a `COLS` variable, very handy.

Answer (score 2):

`2000 * 2000` is only `4000000`. So... just store a list of integers
and use modulo math to transform into 2-d coords in your application
code.

So, for `(row, col)` coords of (varying the y's to make it clearer,
and omitting `y==2000` since that's, you know, not `<2000`)

```
(850, 1999)
(950, 1289)
(1050, 380)
```

you'd do (python example)

```
>>> COLS = 2000
>>> xy2num = lambda x, y: (x*COLS)+y
>>> num2xy = lambda n: (n // COLS, n % COLS)
>>> points = [(850, 1999), (950, 1289), (1050, 380)]
>>> point_nums = [xy2num(x, y) for x, y in points]
>>> point_nums
[1701999, 1901289, 2100380]
>>> [num2xy(num) for num in point_nums]
[(850, 1999), (950, 1289), (1050, 380)]
```

One way to think about this is as an enumeration of each point on the
map:

```
[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), <...>, (0,1999),
 (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), <...>,
 (1999,0), (1999,1), <...>, (1999, 1999)]
```

Each `0<=N<4000000` integer is essentially an index lookup into this
list.

Note that there's nothing special about this being 2D - can work for
an arbitrary number of dimensions (tho of course the numbers involved
start to get prohibitively large).

More fun reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Comment: Damn! That's awesome. Is there any collision?

Comment: Assuming you mean the same integer mapping to two possible points,
and/or two integers that map to the same point, nope. I've updated the
answer with another way you can think about what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

To store it as small as possibile probably I'd just use

```
[x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn]
```

then you can easily recreate your `Position` class instances from the list with

```
positions = map(Position, L[::2], L[1::2])
```

assuming the constructor takes `x` and `y` as parameters

Comment: +1 for the small size, but honestly I find the data structure strange.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear , how big is your map, but generally map would have huge data, so suggest you to go with GridFs rather than storing in collection.

Answer (score 0):

Other work around is two location cannot point to the same position, so "X+Y" can become your ID and your search 0,"position":[X,Y]}